# Cypher to query when a relationship doesn't exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a pattern like so. A person can make visits `(v:Visit {type:'introduction'})` to a property, visits can have different types, such as *inventory check*, *inspection*....

Visits have a chronology which is described by a `(v:Visit)-[r:NEXT]->(vn:Visit)`relationship. At a visit the person may recommend that another visit is scheduled (it may or may not be booked) `(v:Visit)-[r:RECOMMEDED]->(i:Inspection)`

My question is, is it possible to shape a Cypher query to find visit nodes which have a `[r:RECOMMEDED]->(i:Inspection)` pattern which DON'T have a Visit of `{type: 'inspection'}` within 2 `[:NEXT]` hops?

I have this but I have the issue that it return a collection of relationships.

```
MATCH (v:Visit)-[r:RECOMMENDED]->(i:Inspection)
WITH v
MATCH (v)-[n:NEXT*1..2]->(vis:Visit)
WHERE NOT((v)-[n]->(vis:Visit {type:'Inspection'}))
RETURN v
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Check shortestPath() function.

Comment: I don't see how it can return a collection of relationships, so maybe I misunderstand the question, but can't you just replace lines 2-4 with `WHERE NOT v-[:NEXT*1..2]->(:Visit{type:'Inspection'})`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try `OPTIONAL MATCH` where you insist that what you want is null, like this:

```
MATCH (v:Visit)-[r:RECOMMENDED]->(i:Inspection)
OPTIONAL MATCH (v)-[n:NEXT*1..2]->(vis:Visit)
WHERE vis is null
RETURN v
LIMIT 10
```

An `OPTIONAL MATCH` lets you look for a pattern that may or may not be there.   The `WHERE vis is null` insists that it not be there.  So that's your proof that those `Visit` items don't have other downstream `Visit` nodes.

Comment: Many thanks, I had to add `WITH v, vis` before the WHERE to get it working. Not sure why :S